# Connecting to the switch via SSH using and JSch

Tags: java, ssh, switch-statement, jsch

I am trying to write a scrip for connecting with SSH to the Switch Alcatel-Lucent 7210 SAS-X and sending some commands and receiving outputs, using API JSch. But unfortunately it doesn’t work with connection type «exec» - exit status -1.
When I use connection type «shell» with Input/Output thought console everything work fine.
Could somebody help me?
Below is my script.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class SSHTunel2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String IPaddress_server="X.X.X.X";
    String User_server="admin";
    int Port_server=22;
    String Password_server="1111111";
    String Switch_command ="show version";
           try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        // Connection to the Server
        Session session1=jsch.getSession(User_server, IPaddress_server);
        session1.setPassword(Password_server);
       Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session1.setConfig(config);
        session1.connect();           

     System.out.println("session1.getServerVersion():"
                              +session1.getServerVersion();
     System.out.println("The session has been established to   
            +User_server+"@"+IPaddress_server);

        //Command execution
        Channel channel=session1.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(Switch_command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();

        //            Channel channel=session1.openChannel("shell");
        //            channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        //            channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        //            channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channel.isClosed()){
                if(in.available()>0) continue;
                System.out.println("exit-status:       
                                     "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session1.disconnect();

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

 /* Output */
session1.getServerVersion(): SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.5p1
The session has been established to admin@10.44.93.106
in.available(): 0
exit-status: -1

 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: why did you set the channel input stream to null and a line later try to get it?